# Request Date field from MySql DB and save in Windows Store APP class field

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, date, datetime, windows-store

I have a MySQL db with a field that is a Date, to use in a windows store app.

I'm using entity framework to do the requests to the DB.
I have a class with a field of type DateTime.

What I want is to get the date from the DB field and insert it into the class.

As code, I've got:

```
var user2 = (from u in db.challenge

select u).ToList();

foreach (var u in user2)
       {
          utilizadores.Add(new ChallengeTest
          {          
            date= u.datefield,
                });
           }
```

I've tryed u.date, u.date.value.Date, but allways gives me :

> An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

If i mouseover the u.date.(...), it says that is a DateTime?. Also tryed to change my local class field into DateTime? but it still doesnt work.

Any fix or sugestions how I should do it?
Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, fixed it. If someone else has this problem,

Set DateTime on MySql with Non Null (else you have to declare "Datetime?" as nullable in c#)